# How to find ports marked as filtered by nmap

Tags: nmap

I have a host where if the command:

```
nmap <host ip>
```

is run, then get response:

```
All 1000 scanned ports on <host ip> are closed (958) or filtered (42)
```

So I want to find out which ports are those marked filtered and also to find the reason or at least some evaluation of why filtered was reported.

I tried:

```
nmap -sT -oG report1.txt -vv --reason --append-output <host ip> >report2.txt

nmap -oG report1.txt -vv --reason --append-output <host ip> >report2.txt
```

but I don't see any more info about filtered.  I get:

```
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.7.1 are closed because of 1000 resets
```

ie nothing about ports being filtered.  How can I find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ports can be marked "filtered" if either the probe or the response was dropped, especially with aggressive timing levels like `-T5`. Most likely, those 42 ports were closed, but Nmap didn't bother to wait or retry the probe in order to get the TCP RST response that confirmed it. In any case, you are not going to be able to connect to those ports, either.

You are doing the right thing by using `-vv` and `--reason`. This will increase the threshold of number of ports Nmap finds in an ignorable state (e.g. "closed" or "filtered") before it collapses the results into the "Not shown" line.